# How to inject (append) a windowed average into the output using MS Stream Analytics

Tags: azure-stream-analytics

Given a JSON stream that resembles:

`{
    "timestamp": "2017-01-26T20:27:26.099Z",
    "Novato": {
        "humidity": "40.996",
        "barometric": "1011.2"
    },
    "Redmond": {
        "humidity": "60.832",
        "barometric": "1011.8"
    }
}`

For each City in this object, I want to add a new value called humidity_5_second_avg, which is a 5 second tumbling window average.

But of course for each city, it needs to be unique to that city.  And I want to append it to the existing cities' values.

For example:

`{
    "timestamp": "2017-01-26T20:27:26.099Z",
    "Novato": {
        "humidity": "40.996",
        "barometric": "1011.2",
        "humidity_5_second_avg": "38.1234"
    },
    "Redmond": {
        "humidity": "60.832",
        "barometric": "1011.8",
        "humidity_5_second_avg": "32.1234"
    }
}`

Is this possible with a Stream Analytics query?  Or would I need to create two streams (one with the original data, and one with only average data, and merge them together?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is tricky to get exactly in the way described. It’s easier to break down city information into one row per city first and then use JOIN.

```
-- Use CROSS APPLY to split original events into one row per city
WITH CityData AS
(
    SELECT 
        r.PropertyName AS City,
        r.PropertyValue.*
    FROM localinput i TIMESTAMP BY timestamp 
    CROSS APPLY GetRecordProperties(i) r
    WHERE r.PropertyValue.humidity IS NOT NULL
),
Averages AS
(
    SELECT 
        City,
        AVG(humidity) as avg_humidity 
    FROM CityData
    GROUP BY city, TumblingWindow(second, 5)
)

SELECT *, System.Timestamp as ts INTO debug FROM Averages

SELECT 
    c.*, a.avg_humidity
FROM CityData c
JOIN Averages a
ON c.City = a.City AND DATEDIFF(second, c, a) BETWEEN 0 AND 5
```

Comment: I removed this line:

```
SELECT *, System.Timestamp as ts INTO debug FROM Averages
```

and changed localinput to my input, added an 

```INTO```

clause into the last 

```SELECT```

query, and it worked like a charm (took a few minutes for the system to start producing results -- so be patient :) Thanks so much!